# How to generate xsd from custom Java class which extends from java.util.Date by JAXB Schemagen

Tags: soap, jaxb, wsdl, schemagen

I have a custom java class "CustomDate1" extends java.util.Date, and I want to generate XSD file for it by Schemagen. but seems the in XSD file, the "customDate1" doesn't with the extension item, I don't know why, maybe JAXB doesn't support the class which extends Date?

Java Class:

```
public class CustomDate1 extends java.util.Date {
```

}

XSD file:

`<xs:complexType name="customDate1">`

`<xs:sequence/>`

`</xs:complexType>`

Joey

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does your domain object need to extend `java.util.Date`?  Below is a domain class that will generate the XML schema that you are looking for ans may work better for you.

**Domain Model**

We will leverage the `@XmlValue` annotation on the property of type `java.util.Date`.

```
import java.util.Date;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.*;

@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Foo {

    @XmlValue
    private Date value;

    @XmlAttribute
    private String bar;

}
```

**XML Schema**

In the schema below we see there is a type that extends `xsd:dateTime`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<xs:schema version="1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">

  <xs:complexType name="foo">
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="xs:dateTime">
        <xs:attribute name="bar" type="xs:string"/>
      </xs:extension>
    </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:schema>
```

**Schema Generation Code**

The following JAXB code can be used to generate an XML schema from the JAXB model.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.xml.bind.*;
import javax.xml.transform.Result;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Foo.class);

        jc.generateSchema(new SchemaOutputResolver() {

            @Override
            public Result createOutput(String namespace, String suggestedFileName)
                    throws IOException {
                StreamResult result = new StreamResult(System.out);
                result.setSystemId(suggestedFileName);
                return result;
            }

        });
    }

}
```

Comment: Well, thanks your reply, although it's not a direct way problem but still is a way to fix my problem. thanks.